# Jade + AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, pug

Recently, I started reading Jade and I have an experience of working with AngularJS.

I came across certain scenarios where people are using Jade along with AngularJS.

However what I understand is that if we are using AngularJS, we can use AngularJS features(directives majorly) and can avoid Jade.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Jade transpiles into HTML.  Angular manipulates the DOM and attaches itself via HTML.  The two of these things are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Your suggestion seems fine but I am not able to think of scenarios where Jade + AngularJS combination will prove useful.                        As what I understand is that if I am working with angular, I can use Angular features such as conditional rendering, iterative rendering and transclusions etc. which are equivalent to features provided by Jade. However I understand that Jade provides us with the features to write lesser HTML code or avoid tag's opening and closing brackets but will it be the only reason to use Jade along with AngularJS application. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some points for your answer :

1. Jade is a template engine for HTML
2. Basically used for fast processing of HTML
3. If you are working with AngularJs then you don't need to use JADE
4. You can define HTML engine with Angularjs & Node.js like this :

   ```
   app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));  

   app.engine('html', require('jade').renderFile);

   app.set('view engine', 'html');
   ```
5. Using HTML instead of Jade makes easier for you to understand HTML code.
6. Jade has a fallback of using its indent and spacing. It makes bottleneck task for anyone to manage spaces or indents/tabs.
7. Angular mostly works with dynamic content and uses XHR requests and response so using JADE according to me  isn't good idea at all.

Currently I'm working with MEAN stack in which I use HTML with Node &  Angular. And hence for my personal views. I should say that plain HTML is best to used rather than any templating engine like JADE, EJS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Jade is simply a way to preprocess HTML, while Angular will bind data from the controller to the view and vice versa, which can be updated through client events.

Answer (score 0):

Jade is just a view engine on the server-side which makes your HTML templates much less verbose with it's cool syntax. Whereas AngularJS runs on the browser (client-side). You can use Jade templates in conjunction with AngularJS, that's what I'm currently doing on one of my projects.

To be honest it has not been a good practice and using them together makes the job a bit confusing but les verbose.